# What's wrong with my neo4j index query in Cypher?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

Using version 1.9 of neo4j community, I have tried index querying with the small "Cineast" dataset and with the "Matrix" dataset. In the webadmin interface, the Cineasts set has an index called Actor.

```
START n=node:Actor("name:*") RETURN n;
```

This should return all actors' names, right? I get no error message, but zero rows.

I know there is an Actor named Paul Norell in there, so I try this but still get the same results.

```
START n=node:Actor(name="Paul Norell") RETURN n;
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? How do I check that the name key/value pair is indexed, or even which ones are in the index?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, always return 0 by where specify the name

Answer (score 4):

As answered in the google group:

`Actor.name` is not indexed in that dataset.

just `Actor.id` and `Movie.id` and there is a "search" index for movie titles.

```
START n=node:Actor('id:*') RETURN count(*);

START n=node:Movie('id:*') RETURN count(*);
START n=node:Movie(id="601") RETURN n;

START n=node:search('title:*') RETURN count(*);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
START n=node:Actor(name="Paul Norell") RETURN n;
```

`name="Paul Norell"` is a property of node you index in Actor. But the query goes right when you find with key and value of index indexing node.

Eg : when you index node x in Actor with key and value is : name="Paul Norell", your query is right! **Note: key & value when you indexing**